# Secondary namenode on Hadoop 2.x (Hortonworks)

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, standby

I am learning hadoop 2.x technology in Hortonworks, cloudera, and I have noticed that there is no *secondary namenode* in the architecture of hadoop 2.x; it was replaced by a *standby namenode*.

- Is the *secondary node* deprecated? For what I understood, the *standby namenode* functions differ from the secondary namenode functions.
- Can I build *Hadoop* without a *secondary namenode* and *standby namenode* without loss of performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per my knowledge both secondary and standby has a different function.standby namenode is used in case of HA cluster

for your question

1.Secondary node is not deprecated,however if you are setting up HA cluster then you may not need to use Secondary namenode because standby namenode  keep its state synchronized with the Active namenode

2.you can have a hadoop setup without secondary or standby node without any loss of performance but in case of namenode failure all your data will be lost as namenode stores all its metadata in memory

Comment: CTDex, You mean to say that standby namenode is also taking care of merging fsimage file with edits file? or else edits file will be big and surely we need to have that functionality done by somenode. Therefore I believe we need SNN. Please explain.

Comment: in case of  HA setup of namenode,the standby namenode does the job of merging fsimage file with edits file

Answer (score 3):

Secondary namenode and standby namenode are different things.

The old 'secondary' namenode was largely a [misnomer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEqQMLSXQlY). All it did was checkpointing the fsimage from time to time in order to allow for a faster recovery of the real namenode, in case of a crash. By no means it offered any standby/high availability functionality. You should **not** use this.

The new standby namenode is a true standby, high availability feature. Read more about it at [HDFS High Availability](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html):

> Prior to Hadoop 2.0.0, the NameNode was a single point of failure (SPOF) in an HDFS cluster. Each cluster had a single NameNode, and if that machine or process became unavailable, the cluster as a whole would be unavailable until the NameNode was either restarted or brought up on a separate machine.
>
> This impacted the total availability of the HDFS cluster in two major ways:
>
> In the case of an unplanned event such as a machine crash, the cluster would be unavailable until an operator restarted the NameNode.
> Planned maintenance events such as software or hardware upgrades on the NameNode machine would result in windows of cluster downtime.
> The HDFS High Availability feature addresses the above problems by providing the option of running two redundant NameNodes in the same cluster in an Active/Passive configuration with a hot standby. This allows a fast failover to a new NameNode in the case that a machine crashes, or a graceful administrator-initiated failover for the purpose of planned maintenance.

You should use/configure a standby namenode.

On current release (2.6 at time of writing) you have two HA modes:

- [Quorum Journal Manager](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html)
- Using [NFS shared storage](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html)

For Hortonworks distro specific documentation, refer to [NameNode High Availability for Hadoop](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.2/bk_system-admin-guide/content/ch_hadoop-ha.html).

Comment: I got that SNN doesnt do the job of standby node. is the reverse true? that is standby node does the job of SNN. As it maintains hot backup, is it merging fsimage and edits files periodically? explain me please.

Comment: @JagadishTalluri please ask a separate question

Comment: As requested, I asked in separate question. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196981/is-stand-by-namenode-doing-the-job-of-secondary-namenode-also